# Show extra fields when logging to console in python

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a basic setup from a `logging.ini` file so that my console prints human readable logs, but I print JSON dict-like logs to file, so my ELK can process the logs.

```
[formatter_json]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s - %(levelname)s:%(message)s
```

When logging messages, I often add extra fields, ad-hoc, like so:

```
logger.info("hello world, I like the word %s", "cowabanga", extra={"more":15})
```

And so the field `more:15` appears in the log line in my file. But it does not appear in the console, which would just say `2019-06-12 13:25:02,189 root - INFO:hello world, I like the word cowabanga`
. What do I need to do to have `15` or `more:15` appear (I don't care exactly in what order the extra parameters would appear, just that they appear)?

Comment: It seems like adding `%(args)s` to the formatter does the trick. This is almost perfect, but for the fact it will not add just the `extra` params, but also any other arguments. If anyone has a solution that would add only the extra params, it'll be better. But this is good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

The `extra` parameter is just ignored by the standard formatter.

That means that you will need a custom `Formatter` to nicely process the additional arguments. For example this class looks for extra parameters in the LogRecord and if any adds `- extra {key: value, ...}` to the message:

```
class ExFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def_keys = ['name', 'msg', 'args', 'levelname', 'levelno',
            'pathname', 'filename', 'module', 'exc_info',
            'exc_text', 'stack_info', 'lineno', 'funcName',
            'created', 'msecs', 'relativeCreated', 'thread',
            'threadName', 'processName', 'process', 'message']
    def format(self, record):
        string = super().format(record)
        extra = {k: v for k,v in record.__dict__.items()
             if k not in self.def_keys}
        if len(extra)>0:
            string += " - extra: " + str(extra)
        return string
```

Demo:

```
>>> log = logging.Logger('foo')
>>> hnd = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
>>> hnd.setFormatter(ExFormatter())
>>> log.addHandler(hnd)
>>> log.log(logging.INFO, 'foo', extra={'bar': 'baz'})
foo - extra: {'bar': 'baz'}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge! Do you have any idea how I could use pformat with the extra dict? I tried to add `string += str(pformat(extra, sort_dicts=False))` to see if I can pformat the extra dict in the message, but it does not work.